# Algorithm to count the number of partitionings?

Tags: algorithm, math, partitioning

*Recently, I ancountered the problem to evenly disperse different width-sized, small containers into huge width-sized containers horizontally. There are millions of huge containers with billions of small containers. I need to come up with an algorithm. I simplified the problem into the below question:*

**Let's use 
`Process(Number,Parts)` as an example:**

Number `4` can be split into `2` parts in 3 ways (not including 0).  `Process(4,2)=3`:

```
1 + 3
3 + 1
2 + 2
```

Likewise, number `4` can be split into `3` parts in 2 ways `Process(4,3)=2`:

```
1 + 1 + 2
2 + 1 + 1
1 + 2 + 1
```

And obviously `Process(4,4)=1`

(not including `Process(4,1)=1`, because it is `4+0`, where `0` shouldn't be taken into consideration)

I wonder whether there is any way to calculate

`SuperProcess(4)=Process(4,2)+Process(4,3)+Process(4,4)=7`

with less time complexity? Or with another word, faster!!

Especially when the request is to calculate: `SuperProcess(1209)`

Is there some mathematical method rather than a crude loop to perform this calculation?

Comment: Seems closely related to the Catalan number: Convert n to 1+1+1+1+...+1 and then consider all ways to insert parentheses.

Comment: One way to approach a problem of this kind is to work out, by hand, what are the first few terms in the sequence Super(1), Super(2), Super(3), ... and look up that sequence in the amazing Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (https://oeis.org).

Answer (score 2):

`SuperProcess(n)` is known as the [*number of compositions of an integer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) rather than the [*number of partitions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) in which sums containing the same addends are considered identical independent of ordering.

There are exactly `2**(n-1)-1` compositions for a positive integer `n` excluding the sum with only one addend.

Therefore the best algorithm to calculate `SuperProcess(n)` is simply to evaluate the expression `2**(n-1)-1`, which can be done in `Theta(n)` time.

If you want to enumerate all combinations, this can be done with a recursive function taking every value `1...n` for the integer `m` in the current position in the sum and then recursively calling itself with `n-m` for the next position, stopping on `0` argument.

The enumeration algorithm will take `Theta(n 2**n)` time and this is optimal, because it is the time required to save/print all the combinations explicitly.